# Is there an immutable and read-only collection type in .NET?

Tags: c#

In .NET we have both read-only and immutable collection types.
For instance:

- [`ReadOnlyCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.readonlycollection-1?view=net-7.0) is a read-only wrapper around a list. Instances of this type cannot be modified by the client code (so this type is read-only), but if the underlying list changes, then those changes are reflected on the `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` instance (so, this type is not immutable).
- [`ImmutableList<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablelist-1?view=net-7.0) is an immutable type (once you have an instance of the type, there is no way to modify it by changing the object state), but it's public interface is not a read-only interface: the client code can call methods (such as the [`Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablelist-1.add?view=net-7.0) method) whose purpose is creating new instances of the type, without modifying the current instance.

Sometimes I feel the need for a concrete type which is both immutable and read-only.
Based on my knowledge, there is no existing type in the .NET base class library having both of these characteristics. Am I missing anything ?

The closest you can get is by using interface types, such as in the following example:

```
public IReadOnlyCollection<string> GetItems()
{
  // the returned collection is an immutable object and is seen as read-only by the client code
  return new List<string>{ "foo", "bar" }.ToImmutableList();
}
```

Comment: Well, the example you showed is exactly what you need, isn't it? It is a `IReadOnlyCollection<string>` whose underlying collection is immutable, so no changes would be reflected on it at all. Why do you specifically need a *concrete* type?

Comment: Honest question, why would one actually need an immutable list type?

Comment: If you have an immutable list stored in a variable or field to which only you have access, nothing anybody else does to that instance has any material effect on that variable or field. And if someone else does have access to that variable or field, they can change what it's referencing *no mater what type you're using*. So I suspect you're mistaken and you really do just need an `ImmutableList<T>`.

Comment: `it's public interface is not a read-only interface` Yes, it is. Just because you can call a method that returns a modified copy of the list, that doesn't mean that the interface is not read only.

Comment: @MatthewWatson you are right. As pointed out by JonasH in its answer, being immutable implies being readonly. The methods available in the public interface of immutable types are just shortcuts to create new objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Immutability implies read only.

The `ImmutableList<T>.Add` method does not modify the object. It is just a shortcut for creating a new object. It is very similar to something like `Enumerable.Concat`, something that is also available on `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`. So the object itself remains immutable and read only.

The distinction between read only and immutable in this context is if *someone else* can modify the collection. `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` is just a wrapper around a list, so it is still possible for someone else to change the list. `ImmutableList<T>` promises that *no one* can change the list. But this distinction is not 100% consistent in the language. The `readonly` keyword is for example used to mark structs as immutable.

Comment: Probably that's just a matter of terminology. As you pointed out, the usage of these nouns is not fully consistent across the language. Anyway your point about "shortcuts to create new objects" is really useful and it makes me better understand the whole topic.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a step back and agree on what the terms readonly and immutable means.

1. A `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` cannot be modified. However, the list of objects that it refers to can be modified (unless those objects are immutable).
2. An immutable list cannot be modified. The list of objects that it refers to, cannot be modified either. That's the difference.

In other words, all immutable collections are readonly. You're getting exactly what you're asking for.

From docs:

> ... *When you add or remove items from an immutable list, a copy of the
> original list is made with the items added or removed, and the
> original list is unchanged*...
>
> `ImmutableList<T>` **Implements**
> `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablelist-1?view=net-7.0